# findViewByID does not work when used virtually or normally

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I created a class (not MainActivity) that needs to write to an element in the activity_main.xml UI.

The element in question is declared as the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/beatBarRenderView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

All I'm trying to do is draw on the view by doing the following:

```
beatBarRenderView.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
```

The bitmap is correctly declared before this line.

The code seems to be able to find beatBarRenderView, because I don't get any errors during compilation. However, during runtime, the program crashes and I get the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

So what I tried to do is declare beatBarRenderView in this class manually by doing the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    beatBarRenderView = findViewByID(R.id.beatBarRenderView)
}
```

Now I get a compilation error:

> Unresolved reference: findViewByID

Keep in mind that I've read similar questions on this site. I've added kotlin-android-extensions to build.gradle already. I think I imported the correct libraries (Android Studio doesn't recommend any for the compilation error, it just tells me to create an abstract class). This worked in MainActivity and only broke when I moved it to another class file.

Comment: It seems like you might be conflating layouts with runtime `View` objects, and the Kotlin synthetics are only adding more confusion. Layouts are just blueprints. A `View` created from a layout in one `Activity` has no relation to a `View` in another `Activity` created from that same layout. If you want to modify a `View` in `MainActivity` from some other class, then you'll need to pass `MainActivity`'s `View` to it directly. Also, your second class would appear to be extending some `Activity` class, and it seems you're instantiating it yourself.

Comment: You cannot create instances of `Activity` classes yourself, and have them work correctly, which is likely why you got that `Window.findViewById(int)` Exception.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewByID` change to `findViewById`

if not, add `as` for type like this

```
lateinit var mTextHello: TextView

public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mTextHello = findViewById(R.id.ui_text_hello) as TextView
    mTextHello.text = "Kotlin Example"

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Changing the capital D to lowercase d did let me use the function normally, and I've also added "as ImageView" for good measure (it was an ImageView, not a TextView). Now I am getting this error during runtime (crashes): "lateinit property beatBarRenderView has not been initialized". I'm starting to wonder if I'm completely misunderstanding what onCreate does...

Comment: lateinit it make Late initialization. So check this part

Comment: Could you explain? What do you mean by this? Should I initialize it with the rest of the class's local variables?

Comment: if you use `lateinit ` you have make `var` variable. So it should initialize. check docs. https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/lateinit-kotlin/